# Maven 3.8.5 and newer file-path sensitivity in Profile activation based on file exists

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project sub-module that requires a database password for a code generation build phase. I do not wish to place this password in any file that is committed to version control. This is not a production instance password, but I wish to keep the password as secure as possible in any case.

Developers working on this module must place the password in a profile in settings.xml. Additionally, it is preferred that this profile is not active by default and is only active when building this specific project. So the profile is activated by the presence of the 'my-sub-module/pom.xml' file.

settings.xml:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>db-password</id>
      <properties>
        <my.db.password>secret-password</my.db.password>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <exists>my-sub-module/pom.xml</exists>
        </file>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

This worked great, right through Maven version 3.8.4. But it does not work for any newer Maven 3.8.x versions or Maven 3.9.x. Note that it relies on the `my-sub-module` directory path in the `<exists>` element to make it somewhat specific to this project.

For older Maven, the following commands output the password as expected in both cases:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=my.db.password -q -DforceStdout
mvn help:evaluate -pl my-sub-module -Dexpression=my.db.password -q -DforceStdout
```

With newer Maven the first command above, outputs the password as expected, but the second command does not. It says "null object or  invalid expression".

So clearly something changed in Maven regarding the "relative-ness", if you will, of the path specified in `<exists>`. So when running a full Maven build on the parent module with 3.8.5 or greater, the context for  seems to be different when it builds the sub-module.

I tried removing the `<activation>` block from settings.xml and adding profile activation directly in my-sub-module/pom.xml or the parent pom.xml, thus not requiring any  criteria

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>db-password</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

But Maven does not merge the property defined in the settings.xml profile into the environment at runtime. It seems like it should but the docs were not definitive on that point.

I have come up with a workaround, but I think it will only work if I and all other developers edit settings.xml AND update Maven to 3.8.5 or newer. By referencing an arbitrary file (with a more unique name than pom.xml) that exists in the root directory of the submodule (such as activate-my-db-password.txt) in the `<exists>` element without any path, then a full build of the parent project will work as it did before.

I am not terribly pleased with that workaround.

So, is there a totally different approach to this in Maven that I am missing? I know that one can encrypt a password in settings-security.xml, but that seems to be for Maven repositories only. Or is there some way to decrypt such a password for use in an arbitrary maven plugin configuration?

Is the failure to get the profile property from settings.xml when activation is enabled in the pom.xml a Maven bug?

Clearly, Maven functionality changed on a patch-release, so consider me annoyed with that, no matter if my approach to managing this password is sane or not.

Comment: uesrname/password management should not be done with properties, but with server-entries in the settings.xml. So to correct you a bit, this is not just for repositories. However, the specific maven-plugin must be capable to use this. Here's an example with a database: https://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#settingsKey

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin I am using only supports plain maven properties. The plugin author says "don't use a production database", which we don't, but I still don't want the password to our development database floating around.

Comment: Update to 3.8.8+

Comment: @Michael-O As stated in the question, the issue is the same on 3.9.x

Comment: Then you should file a JIRA issue if this seems to be regression along with a reproducer.